# Wordpress visual editor help / border change on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make some changes in the Wordpress visual editor. Basically, I already have a border around an image and I want the border to change width and padding when the mouse hovers it. Here is my current code:

```
img class="wp-image-162 size-medium aligncenter" 
style="border: 5px solid #696262; 
padding: 5px; 
margin: 0px;"
```

What code should I add so that the border changes when the mouse touches the image?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off not using inline-css like this, meaning preferably use:

```
<style type="text/css">
img.size-medium{border: 5px solid #696262; padding: 5px; margin: 0px;}
img.size-medium:hover{border: 12px solid blue;}
</style>
```

If you are sticking to the inline-css, use !important

```
img.size-medium:hover{border: 12px solid blue !important;}
```

Comment: Yes, very nice. Thank you.

Comment: Django, can I mix and match my old CSS and inline-CSS without any problems arising?
Why do I have to use !important?

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be working. Would you mind telling me how to implement it?